# How to create a JS Date object from weekday and time string

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns

Given a string like `Tue:18-20` how can one create a Javascript date object that represents the first/next Tuesday at 18:00 (from now)

For context: Above string format is used to store a users' pick-up and delivery times preferences. Keen to hear if there'd be a better approach to store this (either as a string or different format)

Comment: Is this used for an ongoing preference, meaning every Tuesday between those times, or for a specific one-time event? If it's the latter then you are better off storing start, end timestamps to begin with.

Comment: String is used for ongoing preference. Also, multiple strings are stored for a user (i.e a user can store many two hour slots for each day if the week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write a code to decode your `<day>:<startHours>-<endHours>` string. Then, You can do it like this

```
let day = 1; // Mon : 1, Tue: 2, Wed: 3 ...
let startHours = 18;
let endHours= 20;

// get the start of the period
let dateStart = new Date();
dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate() + (day !== dateStart.getDay() ? (day + 7 - dateStart.getDay()) % 7 : 7));
dateStart.setHours(startHours, 0, 0, 0)
console.log(dateStart)

// get the end of the period
let dateEnd = new Date();
dateEnd.setDate(dateEnd.getDate() + (day !== dateEnd.getDay() ? (day + 7 - dateEnd.getDay()) % 7 : 7));
dateEnd.setHours(endHours, 0, 0, 0)
console.log(dateEnd)
```

Comment: @G.W does this answer the intended problem?

Comment: Thanks @Amilia, I just tested your solution and it works well except that it uses the same day if the input string is after now. For example, if now = Friday, April 23 08:00 and the input = Friday April 23 09:00 it outputs Friday, April 23, 08:00 instead of Friday April 30 09:00. Any suggestions on how to ensure it outputs first/next available date?

Comment: @G.W, if the day of the week today(Friday: 5) is the same as the next day(Next Friday: 5) then we can just add 7 days to the date of now. I have updated the answer considering that specific case as well. Can you please check?